# Choosing Couples From A Group

Tags: combinatorics

The is a Ballet group with 22 people 10 are women and 12 are men.
we take 5 women and 5 men, and arrange them as couples how many options there are?

What I did is ${ 12 \choose 5}+ { 10 \choose 5}$ but I think I have missed something as I did not used the number 22

Answer (score 1):

I think $$\binom{10}{5}\cdot \binom{12}{5}\cdot 5!$$ where the $5!$  is due to the construction of the couples after choosing $5$ men and $5$ women

Comment: if so shouldnt it be $$\binom{10}{5}\cdot \binom{12}{5}\cdot 5!\cdot 2!$$?

Comment: @gbox: why $2!$ ?

Comment: the couples can switch places between themselves

Comment: @gbox: ah ok, I suppose the couple are unordered; moreover, with your hypotheses the factor should be 2^5

Comment: @gbox: I mean $2^5$